# Best way to pass connection string to DAL?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a winforms project in a tiered environment. There is a service layer, a processor layer and finally a data access layer. Really, the client doesn't matter - it could be winforms, web etc. The data access layer is using EF. The client applications allow the user to select the database during the login screen, so my DBContext can't be hard-coded to one database. What is the best way to get the DBContext to use the connection selected by the client without having to pass the connection string in with every call to the service layer (to be passed down to the DAL)?

Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This would be possible by constructing a `DbConnection` object on your presentation layer and passing it your connection string. Then you pass that to your service layer which then passes it to your DAL, which constructs a `DbContext` object with it. This is generally not recommended though, because your presentation layer should be ignorant of data access implementation/libraries.

Comment: Is the service layer something like a separate web service, or do the layers all run in the same app domain?

Comment: Thanks @CircularReference, I'm looking for a way that I don't have to pass the connection string or DBConnection to every service call, that would just be a huge pain.

Comment: @GertArnold, currently the service layer is just another class library project referenced by the presentation layer.

Comment: Well, then it's easy. The context reads its connection string from the config file of the executing assembly. See the given answer.

Comment: The answer didn't specify which .config file it was referencing. That is nice, but I may not know the connection string ahead of time. And If I have many connection strings to choose from, how do I tell the DBContext which one to use? I would have to pass it down through the layers to the DAL, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. The solution by Jake requires that I have all of the connection strings in the web.config file (not an option) and that I pass the name of the connection string being used through each method call in every layer. Or, have one connection string that I just update at run time (this did not work). So, this is what I came up with that works and doesn't require me to pass the connection string name or actual connection string with every call through every layer.

1) Added a connection string variable to each dal class:

```
Private ReadOnly _connectionString As String
```

2) Added 2 constructors to each DAL class

```
    Public Sub New()

        _connectionString = My.Settings.PrimaryConnectionString

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal connectionString As String)

        _connectionString = connectionString

    End Sub
```

This allows me to default to a database specified in the DAL's settings and allows me to access my DBContext in a uniform way throughout the application.

Then, I follow the same pattern up through my processors and services layer. I declare a connection string variable and two constructors, one with a connectionString parameter and one without.

Service Field:

```
Private ReadOnly _documentProcessor As DocumentProcessor
```

Service Constructors:

```
Public Sub New()

    _documentProcessor = New DocumentProcessor()

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal connectionString As String)

    _documentProcessor = New DocumentProcessor(connectionString)

End Sub
```

This way, when I instantiate my Service I pass in the connection string once for as long as I want to use that particular instance of that service. The constructors in the processor and dal handle setting the connection string there so I just need to pass in once per instance of each service. I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the connection string in your app.config or web.config file in the connectionStrings section. Then pass the name of the connection string to the base DbContext in you [DbContext's constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx).

#### app.confg

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection[" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

#### DbContext

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
     public MyContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
}
```

Comment: Right, but doesn't this mean I have to pass the connection string in every method from the UI down through the other two layers to the dal method? Maybe I am misunderstanding...

Comment: The connection string name that is, as referenced in the app.config of the client project.